# Angular-QueryBuilder: Dynamically changing fields

Tags: angular, jquery-query-builder

Is there a way to dynamically change which fields are available to [Angular-QueryBuilder](https://github.com/zebzhao/Angular-QueryBuilder)?

I've tried:

1. **Updating the `fields` property of my `QueryBuilderConfig`.**

   - Nothing happens.
2. **Removing and re-adding the component using `ngIf` and `ChangeDetectorRef`.**

   - The fields do update.
   - However, now certain fields break the query builder. When any of those fields is selected, the add rule and add ruleset buttons appear to do nothing. You have to remove the problem field before your additions show up.
   - Video: https://i.imgur.com/UXZgpQ4.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was my field objects. They didn't have `value` properties, so `Angular-QueryBuilder` was creating `value` properties whose values were auto-incrementing integer IDs.

Since I was filtering from a source array without deep-cloning, `value` was also getting set on the objects in the source array. Then the indices would be wrong when items were removed after filtering.